# UIActivity activityViewController crash on iPad in Swift

Tags: ios, ipad, swift, uipopovercontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have the following code below to toggle UIActivityViewController

```
@IBAction func shareButtonClicked(sender: UIButton)
{
    let textToShare = "Text"

    if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/")
    {
        let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

        self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

But it crashes on iPad. How do I present it modally in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will crash because in iPad you can not present `UIActivityViewController` as like in iPhone.

You need to present it in a popover as per the design guidelines suggested by Apple.

The below code will demonstrate how to show present it in a `UIPopoverPresentationController`.

```
@IBAction func shareButtonClicked(sender: UIButton)
{
    let textToShare = "Text"

    if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/")
    {
        let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

        var nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: activityVC)
        nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        var popover = nav.popoverPresentationController as UIPopoverPresentationController!
        activityVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(500,600)
        popover.sourceView = self.view
        popover.sourceRect = CGRectMake(100,100,0,0)

        self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Note: Extend your view controller with `UIPopoverPresentationController` delegate.

For example:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
//........
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error in the line  `popover.delegate = self` stating "/Users/Palash/Documents/xcode/Learn the Basics/Learn the Basics/ViewController.swift:51:28: Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate'"

Comment: Yes because you have to extend your view controller with `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate `, like I just explained at end of the answer. Add `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate ` to your view controller will resolve it.